# Use Row Index value to update SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I want to edit the SQL values.  For some reason I can't get the values to come across like I would like.  This is the first code I tried and couldn't get to work:

```
String acctNum = customerLookup.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
cn2.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update custInfo set acctNum='"+acctNum+"' WHERE customerName='Strathman,Tim'", cn2);
```

This didn't pass through the values like I wanted so I thought I would try using a parameter value like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update custInfo set acctNum = @acctNum where customerName = @customerName3", cn2);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName3", customerDropDown.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctNum", customerLookup.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This didn't work either... it does work when I put a manual entry in like '1234' for the account number so I know it isn't an issue with the customerName Parameter... any clues as to what I'm missing would be great

Comment: if you put a try catch block around it do you get a conversion from varchar or nVarchar to int error on @acctNum?

Comment: also dont use inline SQL like that, its bad practice, if you want to do things like this and parameterise things you should use stored procedures

Comment: Are you able to test the SQL manually - either from a command line or some form of GUI. My first instinct when a query is not working is to get a copy of the command string & try running it manually to see if it works - sometimes just checking the string highlights unexpected or missing spaces, commas etc.

Comment: Also, make sure you have a default database in your connection string or that you have issued a SQL command to set one, otherwise you need to specify where the custInfo table resides.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works great:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)customerLookup.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string acctNum = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```